# Magento 2 admin email templates shows old data

Tags: magento2

if i change template text from admin panel and use that email template in custom email then email is sending but it shows old data only not showing my text even after it is saved in database.

```
    $alltemplele = $this->_objectManager->get('\Magento\Email\Model\Template')->load(7);
$emailTemplate = $alltemplele->getData('orig_template_code');

$storeScope = \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE;
$transport = $this->_transportBuilder
// ->setTemplateIdentifier('send_email_email_template') // this code we have mentioned in the email_templates.xml
  ->setTemplateIdentifier($emailTemplate)
  ->setTemplateOptions(
[
'area' => \Magento\Framework\App\Area::AREA_FRONTEND, // this is using frontend area to get the template file
'store' => \Magento\Store\Model\Store::DEFAULT_STORE_ID,
]
  )
  ->setTemplateVars(['data' => $postObject])
  ->setFrom($sender)
  ->addTo('psuryawanshi@example.com','paras')
  ->getTransport();
  $transport->sendMessage();
```

Can anyone help me how can I get latest text or changes in email template?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks In advance..!

> this is my admin template content :
>   {{template config_path="design/email/header_template"}}

{{trans "Custom Email for subcription"}}

{{template config_path="design/email/footer_template"}}

Comment: may I know what is the email template you are editing.

Comment: i am adding new email template for subscription sucess but it is showing old string i.e. "You have been successfully subscribed to our newsletter".  and i have updated like "Custom string" in database.

Comment: add code for `$postObject` where this variable come from

Comment: my problem is ,the string is not changing its showing old string in email i.e. "You have been successfully subscribed to our newsletter". but i want it should be "Custom string" it is saved in database but still getting old msg

Comment: {{template config_path="design/email/header_template"}}


{{trans "Custom Email for subcription"}}

{{template config_path="design/email/footer_template"}}

this is my template content from admin->marketing->templates.

but i should get the message what i have provided i.e. "Custom Email for subcription"  but iam getting "You have been successfully subscribed to our newsletter." from where iam getting this message. plz help

Answer (score 0):

Suggestions for you:

- Check if the cache is making you a problem.
- Make sure that the correct email template is selected.
- Add some changes to the email templates from the Magento_Sales module and see if there is a change in the email. (This is just for debugging.)

Comment: i am adding new email template for subscription sucess but it is showing old string i.e. "You have been successfully subscribed to our newsletter". and i have updated like "Custom string" in database.

Comment: i tried all these thinks but not works

Comment: Do you have multiple stores? If yes, maybe you should set template for a correct store.

Comment: no i am using default store only

Comment: {{template config_path="design/email/header_template"}}


{{trans "Custom Email for subcription"}}

{{template config_path="design/email/footer_template"}}

this is my template content from admin->marketing->templates.

but i should get the message what i have provided i.e. "Custom Email for subcription"  but iam getting "You have been successfully subscribed to our newsletter." from where iam getting this message. plz help